# How (if possible) to use Groovy dependencies for Fuerte?

Tags: moveit, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*related question*: How to install moveit on fuerte?(http://answers.ros.org/question/47877/how-to-install-moveit-on-fuerte/)

---

I'm trying to install moveit on ROS Fuerte. The problem is that it's available only from source (http://moveit.ros.org/download.html). The dependencies mentioned in the moveit website (http://moveit.ros.org/installation.html), are for groovy but almost all of them have fuerte correspondent. My question is, what can I do for the dependencies that have no fuerte correspondent. These dependencies are as the follow:

```
 ros-groovy-kdl
 ros-groovy-rviz
```

There is also ***ros-groovy-warehouse-ros*** and a package in fuerte called ***ros-fuerte-warehousewg***.

Is there any way to use these groovy packages in fuerte?

P.S. Any tutorial or documentation about installing moveit on fuerte is highly appreciated.

P.P.S. Sorry for badly formated text. My Karma does not allow me hyperlinks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48454/how-(if-possible)-to-use-groovy-dependencies-for-fuerte?/) by [Pouya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3552/pouya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess moveit is still under heavy development and still not officially released or stable. You should be aware of that and I would expect that building it could cause a few problems. I haven't tried the following steps but that's how I would do it:

- Install the fuerte equivalents for all groovy dependencies you find.
- The equivalent packages in ros-groovy-kdl and ros-groovy-rviz are provided by ros-fuerte-visualization and ros-fuerte-orocos-kinematics-dynamics. Install them
- Check out the moveit sourcecode and try to compile it.
- If you run into dependency problems, either install the corresponding debian packages or use roslocate to find their source code location. Always prefer the debain packages.
- If you run into other compiler errors, you'll probably have to dive into the code and fix them.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2